# Creating an arbitrarily distorted 2D grid

Tags: geometry, 2d, computational-geometry, distortion, plane

I want to distort a 2D grid based on the location of point masses. The presence of mass, should contract the grid as follows:

[image: distortion]

But I want to distort it with an arbitrary number of particles on the grid.

This is, so that I can visualize the effect of gravity on space: warped the space where large masses are present.

What I have tried so far, is iteratively adjusting the edges of a cell, based on the number of particles inside it. A cell with many particles should shrink its edges.

However, the resulting visual is disappointing and doesn't really come across as a distorted 2D space. I think because the deformation should have a global effect, and not just an effect on a single cell?

What algorithm could I use to distort a 2D space with particle masses?

[image: attempt]

Comment: Do you have constraints on processing time or memory? Or maybe a rough estimate of the number of particles? One method I can imagine is simple but slow, and another is potentially fast but could be tricky to implement.

Comment: This is for interactive use, so should definitely run at 60Hz or faster.

Comment: Okay. I think I can cobble something together within the next twelve hours. In the meantime, a few additional questions. Would the smallest mass occupy one pixel, or could it occupy a fractional pixel? What is the max display resolution? Although you mentioned an arbitrary number of pixels, is there a practical limit to the number of masses/particles? Can we assume the masses represent spheroids, or do you want to handle weird shapes? Would you have the chance to work with OpenGL (or VTK) or CUDA, or just implement for CPU cores?

Comment: Also: do you want a description of the "real" math, or just something that looks realistic-ish? From your profile I see you write in C, so I'll come up with some C++ code; let me know if you want it to look more like C than C++.

Comment: It's not a pixel-based simulation. It uses vectors, and is computer on CPU, not GPU. Currently I use up to 50K particles or so, all with the same mass. You can try out the existing version without space distortion here: https://bram.itch.io/sprinkle-sprinkle-little-star

Comment: Thanks. The app looks pretty! I'll try a few ideas and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up being so tired I struggled with the naive implementation (for sake of demonstration) and didn't even get to the fast implementation. Long story short, I think there's a fast way to handle superposition of the gravitational pulls from all the masses, but I need a fresher brain to write it up. I'll get back to you when I can.

Answer (score 1):

I would model the 2d plane as made of some elastic material, such that you can deform it applying forces that simulate the weight of a given object.

Since you want to visualize some physical effect I think a physically based visualization can be an adequate choice.

A relatively simple way to simulate such an elastic behavior is creating a mass-spring system:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft-body_dynamics

However applying this type of techniques requires a good understanding of Hookean physics, ODEs, integration and more related mathematical stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I created a fiddle where each particle affects every grid intersection based on the inverse square rule gravity uses. https://jsfiddle.net/1nrjcsqa/2/

```
    dx = points[i][0] - x;
    dy = points[i][1] - y;
    d = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    f = gravity_force / Math.pow(d, falloff);
```

Because gravity falls off as a square of the distance, points only have a visible effect on the grid closest to them. You can make the points effect the grid further away by reducing falloff, but that would be less like gravity.

You may need to adjust gravity_force to make things look right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post a few quick suggestions for now, and then follow up more when I can.

Although you said explicitly in your post and comments that this would be processed on the CPU, doing this on the GPU and using OpenGL for display could help a lot. Processing the effects of tens of thousands of points at 60 Hz (~ 16 msec per pass) is asking a lot of a CPU even if it has eight cores.

That said, a few preparatory thoughts:

- As user aptriangle point out, gravity falls off as the square of the distance. At some distance you can ignore the effects, especially since your objects all have the same mass.
- Given that you would support a large number of masses, there are problems of scaling while still maintaining good update rates for interaction and smooth animation.
- Your goal is visualization, which means you may be able to take shortcuts that strict interpretation of the math might otherwise lead you to. In fact, I think at least some shortcuts are necessary to operate at anything near the speeds you want.
- Iterating over masses and all the gridline points they affect likely won't lead to an attractive graphic updating at the speeds you'd like.
- You'll need to account for **superposition** and **field vectors**. (I'm going for a general sense here, not proper terminology.) Each mass will have an effect on all of the space around it. From any point in space, there will be some vector pointing at that mass, which the length of the vector representing the strength of attraction. At any point in space, you'll add up the vectors. This can yield a "dead spot" where two different bodies pull with forces that cancel out.
- With lots of masses, the visualization of curved gridlines may become so complicated it confuses rather than enlightens the user. Imagine a stretchy rubber sheet with thousands of steel weights attached to it, sometimes with the weights clustered together: the surface shape could look really complexly weird.
- As Mauricio Cele Lopez Belon wrote, you could model the surface as an elastic material--that is, directly implement "rubber sheet" surface geometry. Short of using CUDA and OpenGL on the GPU I don't think you'll get this to work, though.
- The main obstacle is calculation time.
- To minimize calculation time, precompute as much as possible.
- Note that since your masses are equal, the effects of those masses at any given (dx,dy) offset is the same.
- Although the points representing masses may have real-valued locations, such as (23.32342, -15.38963) or whatever, you likely can (and probably need to) calculate the effects on an integer-based grid to simplify computation.

Given all that, I have in mind a fast technique that defines the gravitational field about each mass as a chunk of memory that gets (more or less) ORed together with other memory to yield a final map of field vectors.

Then there's the matter of drawing it. Again, using OpenGL to create a true 3D representing that is then projected onto a 2D display would be my preferred way to go. OpenGL can run on integrated graphics, and that's how I'd recommend going. Otherwise the calculations to do modify 2D gridlines as 2D figures could be complicated.

That aside, there are likely additional tweaks, cheats, and workarounds to yield something reasonable that will help the user visualize what's going on, but without representing gravitational fields as accurately as some might like.

From initial code that I wrote merely to show a slow and less desirable way to tackle the problem, here's a very rough sample of bending gridlines by treating them as points that can be individually pulled towards each mass. This is NOT the way to treat the gridlines realistically; the code also has some bugs.

[image: Rough sample of gridlines bent by mass]

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I have the N-Body sim running already, with tens of thousands of particles, well within 16ms on CPU. The sim is done. What I want overlaid, is a visualization how space is distorted under gravity. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiAiEWqxLWg

Comment: I understood that. To calculate how to bend gridlines based on all the points is going to be hard to squeeze into that same 16msec, especially since I'm still not sure of limits to number of masses, memory, cores, etc. If you have some unused CPU cores and/or could offload to the GPU or integrated graphics would help. If you already have the field defined and/or you have fast lookup for point in integer-valued or real-valued space, then there should be a way to create gridlines as piecewise curves knotted together.